# jQuery Click Function Fires Multiple TImes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single page app.

Inside the NAV is a UL.  The UL contains LI that have nested menus

```
<li>
     <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span class="nav-label">Messages</span><span id="NavMessageTotal"class="label label-warning pull-right">16/24</span></a>
     <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
         <li><a class="nav-link" id="NavMailbox" href="#">Mailbox</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

I have tried using:

```
.off('click', 'selector').on('click','selector')
.on('click', 'selector').off('click','selector')
.unbind()
 var = $('selector').unbind();
```

I have tried using a loop with toggleClass:

```
$('selector').each(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('off');

   if($(this).hasClass('off') == false){
       $('mailBoxContainer').fadeIn(2000, foo); 
   }

});
```

At a minimum I get the click event fired 2 times when I click the anchor with the id `#NavMailbox`. It is only clicked once.

```js
$('#NavEditGalleries').on('click',function () {
  if($(this).attr('active') != 'true'){
    $('.nav-link').removeAttr('active');
    apc.fadeOut(pageFade, function () {
      $('#GalleryEditorContainer').fadeIn(pageFade, console.log('Editor Clicked'));
      $('#NavEditGalleries').attr('active', 'true');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<li id="NavEditors">
  <a href="#" data-selector="NavEditorsMain"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Editors</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
  <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-selector="NavEditorsAbout" onclick="NavClick()" id="NavEditAbout">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-selector="NavEditorsContact" id="NavEditContact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-selector="NavEditorsHome" id="NavEditHome">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-selector="NavEditorsGalleries" id="NavEditGalleries">Galleries</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The code will not all fit.  Links to the files and the full project zip can be found [Here on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z5pus6q0e8bws3r/AADINbecXVUSAj22kTKjkBh8a?dl=0)

Comment: are using .bind() to attach events to the selector ?

Comment: no i am using either the .on('click) or .click methods.  I have never had to use bind with them before.

Comment: the only thing i can think of is that you are delegating a single event multiple times.

Comment: Can you post your working code. I am not even sure what element you are attaching events to!

Comment: Check if .on('click' is being delegated more than one. Also , add e.preventDefault() to avoid the page being reloaded.

Comment: Can you post all code, because I cannot help if code is missing. According to this, it is not complete. Also, the double click firing is not a bug. People always think this and it is always 99% incorrect binding. Form what i have seen.

Comment: Also, debugging it is pretty easy, if you know how to. Use developer tools, and can watch all in real time. jQuery is an amazing language (and I have worked with c, c#, c++, python, and even some ASM. Don't give up on it. Just need to learn to use it fully.

Comment: Yea, if you could put all of your code out there, I can for sure correct your problem. This code doesn't even have some of the elements mentioned in your question. Bound events never just fire for no reason. I agree with @Dynomite.

Comment: I will update the code now.  Good points.

Comment: Can you lamen down what you are saying about binding a bit.  I would appreciate it if anyone that comes across this later gets some really solid information.  I am finding stuff out a piece here, a piece there and it gets very frustrating. Everyone has a different style of doing things and likes to say how to do things but does not really get into why beyond basic stuff.

Comment: The code can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z5pus6q0e8bws3r/AADINbecXVUSAj22kTKjkBh8a?dl=0"

Comment: @Casey let's be clear: jQuery is not a language. It's a JavaScript library.

Comment: Seriously, I understand that. Thanks though. It was a verbal mishap. Sorry though, because it could be misleading to new combers to the development scene. Thanks for correcting it. Though an edit to the comment would probably have done more good.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are at

```
apc.fadeOut(pageFade, function () {
  $('#GalleryEditorContainer').fadeIn(pageFade, console.log('Editor Clicked'));
  $('#NavEditGalleries').attr('active', 'true');
});
```

`apc` contains multiple elements (because it is created from `$('div.TheLoot');`.

Each of these elements is `fadedOut` and then (*for each of them*) you issue the `fadeIn` on the `$('#GalleryEditorContainer')`. Since it happens for each `fadeOut`/`fadeIn` you get multiple logs.

---

Quote from [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) docs

> **complete**
>   *Type: Function()*
>   A function to call once the animation is complete, **called once per matched element**.

---

Moreover you should pass a function as the callback to the `fadeIn`

```
$('#GalleryEditorContainer').fadeIn(pageFade, function(){console.log('Editor Clicked')});
```

---

Solution would be to `fadeOut` all and then issue a single `fadeIn` with the relevant callback.

Something like this

```
apc.fadeOut(pageFade)
   .filter('#GalleryEditorContainer').fadeIn(pageFade, function () {
       console.log('Editor Clicked');
       $('#NavEditGalleries').attr('active', 'true');
   });
```

Comment: I tried isolating the function.  only 1 object is hidden, on completion call the show function for the next object.  It still calls it twice even though I am only using a single item for hide and a singe item for show.  I do understand what you are saying and will correct for this error but I am still having the same issue just less times.